# How to write "if textbox is empty" in Visual C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

I'm writing a program in Visual C++ and I need to test if a TextBox is empty. For example (in pseudo-code):

```
if ( textBox is empty ) { 
   // etc..
}
```

How can I test for this condition?

Comment: There is tons of ways to do this. What library or API are you using? Win32? MFC? Something else entirely? What does your current code look like?

Comment: As nvoight says, it would be useful to see the code you have so far so we get an idea of what you want to do in the context of your project.

Comment: Like this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y34a3dk2.aspx

Comment: For example: i want to calculate velocity (v=d/t), and i  have 3 texboxes, 1 for distance, 1 for time and 1 for velocity. I want a condition that express that:  If one of these textboxes is empty, the value of the textbox would be 0... (Sorry for my english, im from spain)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(textbox.text)){//Your code Here}
```

probably something like this.

Comment: I think your answer is the correct one, but your capitalization is off.  It should be `if(String::IsNullOrEmpty(MyTextBox.Text))`  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing straight Win32 then its like this:

```
if ( SendMessage( hWndTextBox, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0 ) == 0 )
{
}
```

If its MFC, then:

```
if ( textBox.GetWindowTextLength() == 0 )
{
}
```